# Titanium Error communicating with the server: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: proxy, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

After installing Titanium Studio on a Windows 7 pc I attempted to create a new mobile project but received an error indicating I was not logged in and the project was not created. Also note that this pc is behind a ***corporate proxy server*** so when it tried to create the new project it was attempting to communicate with Appcelerator servers to create a new GUID for this project. It was accessing the servers directly not using the corporate proxy.

When I open the Terminal and run the ti command `ti status` it returns I am not logged in. I then run the command `ti login`, enter my username/password and the result is`[ERROR] Error: Error communicating with the server: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Titanium CLI setting for httpProxyServer is empty so no proxy was being used. To verify this run this command and find the httpProxyServer attribute.

```
ti config

cli.httpProxyServer    = ""
```

to set this attribute:

```
ti config --append cli.httpProxyServer http://enter-your-proxy-address-here.com:80

cli.httpProxyServer saved
```

now login:

```
ti login
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.2.0, Titanium SDK version 3.2.0.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/

Username: enter-your-userid-here
Password: **********
Logged in successfully
```

now you will be able to create a new mobile project.

Please note that this post is in regards to an issue that requires an http Proxy.